# Alternative to InvokeRequired

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I searched and got that Dispatcher CheckAccess can be used in place of InvokeRequired in wpf.

This is the code want to convert in wpf

```
  private void ChangeTextBox(string txt)
    {
        if (msg_log.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new UpdateText(ChangeTextBox), new object[] { txt }); 
        }
        else
        {
            msg_log.Text += txt + "\r\n";
        }
    }
```

I tried out this ---->

```
private void ChangeTextBox(string txt)
    {
        if (msg_log.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateText(ChangeTextBox), new object[] { txt }); 
        }
        else
        {
            msg_log.Text += txt + "\r\n";
        }
    }
```

But while running i am getting Error [InvalidOperationException] "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

What i am doing wrong ? Please Help ?

Comment: try `msg_log.Dispatcher.Invoke`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Same error InvalidOperationException

Comment: No you shouldn't get exception. post the current updated code, If possible, a repro also

Comment: private void ChangeTextBox(string txt)
        {
            if (msg_log.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                msg_log.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateText(ChangeTextBox), new object[] { txt }); 
            }
            else
            {
                msg_log.Text += txt + "\r\n";
            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not because of the `CheckAccess` method... it is fine to use that to check whether the call to `Invoke` is required or not. When you call the `Dispatcher`, it is important to ensure that you are calling the correct instance of the `Dispatcher` class.  From the [`Dispatcher` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> In WPF, a DispatcherObject can only be accessed by the Dispatcher it is associated with.  For example, a background thread cannot update the contents of a Button that is associated with the Dispatcher on the UI thread. In order for the background thread to access the Content property of the Button, the background thread must delegate the work to the Dispatcher associated with the UI thread. This is accomplished by using either Invoke or BeginInvoke. Invoke is synchronous and BeginInvoke is asynchronous.

So in your case, if you can access the correct `Dispatcher` instance using the following:

```
msg_log.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()
```

Then as @SriramSakthivel mentioned in the comments, you should access the same instance when calling `Invoke`:

```
msg_log.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateText(ChangeTextBox), new object[] { txt });
```

Comment: yea that wHat i am doing but i am getting InvalidOperationException Error at line

msg_log.Text += txt + "\r\n";

Comment: Then `msg_log.Dispatcher` is *not* the correct `Dispatcher` for you to use. I have a `Dispatcher` property in a class that uses Singleton pattern (so there is only one instance) and on startup, I set it to `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` *from the UI thread*. Then any time that I need to access the `Dispatcher` from the UI thread, I can just use that `Dispatcher` property.

Comment: this worked for me thankz for idea :) 

if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(
                        () =>  msg_log.Text += txt + "\r\n", DispatcherPriority.Normal);
            }
            else
            {
                 msg_log.Text += txt + "\r\n";
            }

Comment: As it can be quite difficult to read code placed in comments, it is customary (but optional) for question authors to edit their questions and to provide a summary of their solution code there.

Comment: M new to stakoverflow :)

Comment: In that case it might be an idea for you to take a look at the pages in the StackOverflow [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). It will help you get the most out of this website.

Answer (score -1):

OP problem solved but just for record a useful helper for dispatcher check is:

```
public void DispatchIfNecessary(Action action) {
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    else
        action.Invoke();
}
```

which can then be called as:

```
DispatchIfNecessary(() => { myUIcontrol.Update(...); });
```